# Prevent user from typing in input more than default result

Tags: javascript, angular

```
validationInput(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13 && this.pageInput) {
    if (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) {
      var inputNumber = parseInt((this.pageInput == undefined ? "" : this.pageInput) + event.key
      );
      return inputNumber !== 0
        ? inputNumber <= this.totalPages
          ? true
          : false
        : false;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Here is my function which validate the pageInput when user type in
Ex: total page 10 and the input which user will type must less than the total page! So user only type the number less than or equal to 10! 
I got the bug that I can not type any number when the input already have number like the picture bellow! 
Because it already have number "2" so I can not type any number when highlight number "2"! I only type the new one only if I clear the number "2"
[image]

Comment: If you use a timeout of `0`, the event will go through at first, which means your code can easily adjust the value: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/jh47gb5v/

Answer (score 0):

```
Try below code. This will work for numpad keys and other numeric keys on the keyboard. I have not added the exclusion list. you can add and else condition and have all the keys that you don't want to be pressed. One more thing, in your code if you press backspace or try to delete the number, then false will be returned and nothing will happen. Also, use this code with keydown event.
validationInput(event) {
        if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)||(event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105)) {
          var inputNumber = parseInt((this.pageInput == undefined ? "" : this.pageInput) + event.key);
          var writeNum = inputNumber !== 0
          ? inputNumber <= this.totalPages
            ? true
            : false
          : false;
          return writeNum;
        }
      }
```